# Baixar lista de produtos de uma nota fiscal eletrônica

Tags: php, nfe

Olá,
Andei pesquisando bastante, mas não encontrei nenhuma documentação, gostaria de saber como baixar os dados de uma nota fiscal eletrônica (cpf cliente e lista de produtos) do estado do rio grande do sul (aparentemente cada estado tem seu próprio sistema), a partir do código de barras.
Tenho uma aplicação que já lê o código de barras, mas retorna um link para uma pagina com interface. pelo que eu li, eu devo usar um api do sefaz, mas as urls e parâmetros que devo enviar não são especificados em nenhum lugar que encontrei.
Alguém saberia como fazer isso ou onde encontrar essas informações?

Comment: Qual que é o grau da sua duvida ? como conectar ? só os endereços dos serviços ? fica mais fácil de saber o que responder, caso contrário é ampla demais

Comment: Olá @AnthraxisBR, tenho duvidas em qual endereço usar e como conectar também